# Get words from noise license plate by Python CV2

Tags: python

I'm doing with license plate but cannot get full words from license plate
[Original image of license plate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTQvz.jpg)
I'm using cv2.THRESH_OTSU for get Contours

```
ret, thre = cv2.threshold(roi_blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
kerel3 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(3,3))
thre_mor = cv2.morphologyEx(thre,cv2.MORPH_DILATE,kerel3)
mask = np.zeros(img.shape, np.uint8)
cont, hier = cv2.findContours(thre_mor,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
areas_ind = {}
areas = []
for ind,cnt in enumerate(cont) :
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if(200<((roi_gray.shape[0] * roi_gray.shape[1]) - area) < 2000):
       continue
    else:
        areas_ind[area] = ind
        areas.append(area)
 areas = sorted(areas,reverse=True)[1:9]

 mask_num = np.zeros(img.shape, np.uint8)
 for c,i in enumerate(areas):
    x1,y1,w1,h1 = cv2.boundingRect(cont[areas_ind[i]])
    cv2.drawContours(mask_num, [cont[areas_ind[i]]], -1, 255, -1)
```

[After threshold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tVT3.jpg)

[Drawcontour loss 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tz7vz.png)